# Select sibling & parent with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, select, cheerio

I've been unable to get access to really simple pieces of HTML using cheerio, I just finished opening up the object `$(this)` object and tracking down exactly what I need. Now an error occurs when there is no object in the stack, like a sibling or child. What's the correct way to select the previous sibling, get it's name, href & content, as well as the parent's css.

```
var code = $('code.lang-javascript, code.lang-js')
dataSet.blocks = []
code.map(function (i, elm) {
  var block = {}
  block.prevSiblingTag = $(this).parent().prev()[0].children[0].name
  block.prevSiblingHref = $(this).parent().prev()[0].children[0].attribs.href
  block.prevSiblingContent = $(this).parent().prev()[0].children[0].text()
  block.parentTag = $(this)[0].name
  block.parentClass = $(this)[0].attribs.class
  block.code = $(this).html()
  dataSet.blocks.push(block)
})
```

I was doing this and it was just a mess.

```
var $parent = $($(this).parent().html())
var $prevSibling = $($(this).parents().prev())
var block = {}
block.parentClass = $parent.attr('class')
block.prevSibling = $prevSibling.html()
block.code = $(this).html()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is if there is no children for the previous sibling then `$(this).parent().prev()[0]` will be null.

So a better to get the jQuery obeject reference to the target element then use it to get the attribute/property values like

```
var code = $('code.lang-javascript, code.lang-js')
dataSet.blocks = code.map(function (i, elm) {
    var block = {}, $this = $(this),
        target = $this.parent().prev().children().eq(0);
    block.prevSiblingTag = target.attr('name');
    block.prevSiblingHref = target.attr('href');
    block.prevSiblingContent = target.text()
    block.parentTag = this.name
    block.parentClass = $this.attr('class')
    block.code = $this.html()
    return block;
}).get();
```

Also since you are using `.map()`, it can return an array

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) not jquery.

Comment: @ThomasReggi I think all the methods used above are supported by cheerio

Comment: The only thing thats not working it the `block.prevSiblingTag = target.attr('name')` should be getting the tag `a` or `code`. I've tried replacing it to `target.name` and `target.tagName` but no luck.

Comment: @ThomasReggi in that case `target.prop('tagName')`

Comment: Nope, still `undefined` for the parent tag `.name` and `.prop('name')` both work, for the `prevSibling` neither work.

Comment: can you share a html sample

Comment: the anchor prevSibling I want is wrapped in a p https://gist.github.com/reggi/f35cf79aac2f9535922d#file-example-html-L121

Comment: @ThomasReggi so try `block.prevSiblingTag = target[0] ?  target[0].name || undefined`

Comment: That did the trick! `block.prevSiblingTag = target[0] ? target[0].name : undefined` THANK YOU SO MUCH!